# Tinymce is removing the inline styles with repeated values

Tags: inline-styles, tinymce-5

I am loading a html to a tinymce 5 editor. If the html contains a div or table or any other element with same style values, the last one is being taken instead of all the values provided.
Eg:

```
<div style="width: calc(100%-10px); width:10px;">Test Content</div>
```

is modified to below:

```
<div style="width: calc(100%-10px);">Test Content</div>
```

I know it is a weird requirement. But I need this in my project. Please help

I tried various options like valid_elements, valid_children etc., but nothing seem to work

Answer (score 1):

Well, it will be good if you mention what is your exact requirement.

```
May be i think you should consider min-width and max-width.
```

In CSS, if you give two values for same property, it will use the last declaration applied to that property.